# Change how Spinner looks

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

first please check this image:

[image]

It shows an Spinner beautiful and nice, my Spinner looks like that:

[image]

Here is all my source code.

**Activity xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="amaz1ngc0de.com.br.spinnertest.MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_paymentType"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </Spinner>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My question is: **How can I achieve the same layout showed at tutorial?**

PS: I have checked this topic: [Correct usage of a Spinner, following material design guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798601/correct-usage-of-a-spinner-following-material-design-guidelines) it says something about themes, but I can't make it work, and the tutorial I'm following is that one: [Spinners](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your tutorial is quite dated, unfortunately. The first screenshot you're showing is in the Holo style. What you've created uses the newer and better Material Design. Good job, you bested the tutorial!

However, if you really wanted to achieve the same effect, you can go backwards to the old look, by setting your activity to use the Holo theme. You can do that in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name="..."
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
```

Or if you are using your custom theme then set is a parent:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

If you want to change the look of just the `Spinner`, not the whole screen, you can use `android:theme` on your `Spinner`:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sp_paymentType"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

Comment: You are the best, just improving your answer you can change the theme at the `Spinner` using the tag `theme`

Comment: I would personally suggest keeping the whole application in one visual style. But you are completely right, that if what you're after is just changing the spinner, then this is how you'd do it.